# Undefined method `detailsFileTag' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My aim is to test a design pattern—in this case the decorator pattern.

I have taken the below code from the `lib/` folder and `controller` folder.
The library file here has a `BasicTag` class which is inherited by class `TaggingDecor` and an another class `DescriptionDecor`.

Now all these three classes have a common function called `detailsForTag`.
This function when is called from controller file as listed below.
The error is

> undefined method `detailsFileTag' for nil:NilClass

and the error line is as tagged below in the code.

```
# the concrete component we would like to decorate
class BasicTag
    def initialize()
        @init_basicTag = "File with no tags"
    end

    # getter method
    def detailsFileTag
        return " test from BasicTag....."
    end
end

# decorator class -- this serves as the superclass for all the concrete decorators
# the base/super class decorator (i.e. no actual decoration yet), each concrete decorator (i.e. subclass) will add its own decoration
class TaggingDecor
    def initialize(r_file)
        @r_file = r_file
        @aTagg = "no tag added"
        @aDescTag = "no description added"
    end

    # override the details method to include the description of the extra feature
    def detailsFileTag
        return @aTagg + @aDescTag
    end
end

# a concrete decorator
class TagDec < TaggingDecor
    def initialize(r_file)
        super(r_file)
        @aTagg = "no tag added"
        @aDescTag = "tagdec description added"
    end

# override the details method to include the description
    def detailsFileTag
        return @aTagg + @aDescTag 
    end
end

# another concrete decorator
class DescriptionDec < TaggingDecor
    def initialize(r_file)
        super(r_file)
        @aTagg = "no tag added"
        @aDescTag = "descriptiondec description added"
    end

# override the details method to include the description
    def detailsFileTag
        return @aTagg + @aDescTag 
    end
end

============================= controller file ============================

  # POST /file_taggings
  # POST /file_taggings.json
  def create
    @file_tagging = FileTagging.new(file_tagging_params)

#####################################################
#rails g scaffold fileTagging filename:string filetag:string filedescription:string
# information For logging the file details into table
  @file_tagging.filename = params[:file_tagging][:filename]
  @file_tagging.filetag = params[:file_tagging][:filetag]
  @file_tagging.filedescription = params[:file_tagging][:filedescription]

########################################################################
# information For logging the file details   
  # create an instance/object of a BasicTag 
    myTagg = BasicTag.new

  # add the extra features to the new car
    if params[:file_tagging][:filetag].to_s.length > 0 then
      myTagg = TagDec.new(myTagg)
    end

    #if params[:file_tagging][:description].to_s.length > 0 then
    #  myTagg = DescriptionDec.new(myTagg)
    #end

    ## populate the Description details - By calling the BASE class and SUPER class as stated above.
#Error is here for the call myTagg.detailsFileTag !
    @file_tagging.filedescription =  myTagg.detailsFileTag

   # retrieve the instance/object of the MyLogger class
  logger = MyLogger.instance
  logger.logInformation("A new file details are: " +  @file_tagging.filesdescription)
  logger.logInformation("A new file details are: ")
#####################################################


    respond_to do |format|
      if @file_tagging.save
        format.html { redirect_to @file_tagging, notice: 'File tagging was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @file_tagging }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @file_tagging.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
============================================================
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I see your code (this is excellent)... but I'm still a bit confused... what's the question? What have you tried and what didn't work for you when you tried it?

Comment: The error is saying that you are calling `detailsFileTag` on a `nil`. Given that the only place you are calling that method is on `myTagg` this means that `myTagg` is `nil` for some reason. Have you tried using a debugger to step through your code and see what the value of `myTagg` is at each step? when it gets initialized is it being initialized properly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes correct its a nill object. So I had by mistake deleted out the ruby file in the model folder, which was created by the scaffold.
model>> FileTagging.rb.